# CellForRowAt not called when switching between apps (gif inside)

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a ChatViewController and chat messages. I initialize the layout for the message bubbles with storyboard constraints and an identifier to change them via code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = chatUser.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "chatUserCell", for: indexPath) as! ChatUserTableViewCell
    print("cellforrowcalled")
    cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi))

    // I check here the message sender
    cell.isFromCurrentUser = messages[indexPath.row].fromUid == UserApi.shared.CURRENT_USER_UID!

    cell.labelChatMessage.text = messages[indexPath.row].chatText

    cell.labelChatMessageDate.text = messages[indexPath.row].chatDate?.dateValue().timeAgo(numericDates: false)

    return cell
}
```

In my ChatCellViewController, I change the constraints according to the "isFromCurrentUser" boolean:

```
var isFromCurrentUser: Bool! {
    didSet {
        labelChatMessage.backgroundColor = isFromCurrentUser ? .systemBlue : .darkGray

        if isFromCurrentUser {
            constraintOtherUserTimestamp.isActive = false
            constraintOtherUserLeading.isActive = false
            constraintOtherUserTrailing.isActive = false
            constraintCurrentUserTimestamp.isActive = true
            constraintCurrentUserLeading.isActive = true
            constraintCurrentUserTrailing.isActive = true
        } else {
            constraintCurrentUserTimestamp.isActive = false
            constraintCurrentUserLeading.isActive = false
            constraintCurrentUserTrailing.isActive = false
            constraintOtherUserTimestamp.isActive = true
            constraintOtherUserLeading.isActive = true
            constraintOtherUserTrailing.isActive = true
        }
    }
}
```

It works as you can see in the .gif, but when I am changing the app and reopen my app, cellForRowAt is not called and I lose my constraints and the View is using the initial storyboard constraints:

[image]

Comment: have you tried calling tableview reload in `viewWillAppear` Looks like cellForRow is not getting called when it comes from background.

Comment: I suggest you to use two different cell one for our and one for another user

Comment: Have you tried applicationWillEnterForeground in your AppDelegate.swift file ? This function will be called when you reopen your app. Because viewdidload and viewwillappear functions won't recalled when you reopen your app from background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should listen to the notification for the app entering the foreground i.e. `UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification`

In your `viewDidLoad()`, add the observer:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(resumeState), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
```

then declare `resumeState()` function, this will be called when the app enters the foreground state.

```
@objc func resumeState() {
    yourTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Also do not forget to remove observer in deinit

```
deinit {
    print("\(self.description) deinitialized")
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call **tableView.delegate = self & tableView.dataSource = self** on **ViewWillAppear**

Comment: @JohnDole did you check layers, if tableView shows on view?